# Openvpn failing to send cURL request through user based script

Tags: bash, curl, openvpn

I am trying to authenticate my OpenVPN clients (with a username and password) using a bash script. Here is part of my server side config:

```
client-to-client
username-as-common-name
client-cert-not-required
script-security 3
auth-user-pass-verify '/etc/openvpn/script/auth.sh' via-env
```

Here is my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
SECRET='mysecret'
RESPONSE=$(sudo /usr/bin/curl https://myvpn.com/somedir/auth.php -d"username=$1&password=$2&secret=$SECRET" --silent)
if [ "$RESPONSE" = "y" ]; then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

When I run it on the command line (`./auth.sh`) it runs fine and authenticates correctly. I have setup my php script on my webserver such that it generates a log everytime it is called, so I know if the request successfully reached. However, when OpenVPN calls the script, the curl request fails to send (authentication fails on client side). My guess is that for some reason OpenVPN doesn't have permission to use cURL? How do I give OpenVPN permission to use curl?

Note: I have tried putting `exit 0` on top of my bash script, and it successfully authenticates the user and connects to the VPN.

Comment: Why do you call curl with sudo?

Comment: I wasn't initially, but I tried anyways in case sudo allowed openvpn to call curl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need sudo, you can do it with:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

SECRET='mysecret'
[ 'Y' = "$(
  /usr/bin/curl \
    --data "username=$1&password=$2&secret=$SECRET" \
    --silent \
    'https://myvpn.com/somedir/auth.php'
)" ]
```

No need to exit with explicit return code, since the test will take care of it?

Comment: Thanks a lot! The request now sends. However, none of the data from the POST request is being received. I am writing the $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password'] to a txt file and it creates the txt file, but it is empty. Is there a reason for this? Also, could you please tell me why my code didn't send the request but yours did? Thanks!